# MySQL Rolling inventory with expiration date

Tags: php, mysql

I am hoping for some guidance that will point me in the right direction regarding balancing inventory with an expiration date.
I looking to know how many of each 'flavor' I have left in inventory and the expiration dates of the inventory.

All items (flavor) received, in my Purchase order table, are time stamped and I capture the expiration date (ie. qty 300 exp_date 7/04/14, qty 200 exp_date 7/14/14) .

All orders (per flavor)are  processed and time stamped (qty 2 6/27/14...), so I could sum up the orders processed in a given day/week or whatever.

What would be the best solution (temp table, query, or something else) that would identify and allow me to display that I have qty 98 w/ exp_date of 7/04 and qty 200 w/ exp date of 7/14 from the above example for display real time?

Here is the schema....

```
-- Table structure for table `flavor`
--
CREATE TABLE `flavor` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `pfamily` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `UPC` varchar(17) default NULL,
  `active_flavor` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  `description` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `priority` tinyint(2) default NULL,
  `weight` decimal(6,3) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='flavors' AUTO_INCREMENT=892 ;

-- Table structure for table `orders`
--

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `customer_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `owner_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `ordnum` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `orddate` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `buyer` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `f_id` int(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  `ord_qty` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `wh_price` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_price` decimal(7,2) default '0.00',
  `last_updated` int(10) default '0',
  `RMA` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `RMA_num` int(10) default '0',
  `RMA_qty` int(3) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=269339 ;

-- Table structure for table `p_orders`
--
CREATE TABLE `p_orders` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `vendor_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `owner_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `p_ordnum` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `p_orddate` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `f_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `qty_rcvd` int(3) default '0',
  `GR` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `exp_date` date default '0000-00-00',
  `date_rcvd` date default '0000-00-00',
  `u_date_rcvd` int(10) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=9216 ;
```

Using a simple query for one model

```
SELECT flavor.id, flavor.model,orders.orddate,orders.quantity  
FROM flavor 
left join orders on orders.f_id = flavor.id
WHERE flavor.id = '1'
```

I get the orders

```
id  model       orddate quantity
1   1000-0001   140622  1
1   1000-0001   140622  1
1   1000-0001   140622  15
1   1000-0001   140622  1
1   1000-0001   140622  1
1   1000-0001   140622  1
1   1000-0001   140622  2
1   1000-0001   140622  2
1   1000-0001   140623  1
1   1000-0001   140623  1
1   1000-0001   140623  2
1   1000-0001   140624  1
1   1000-0001   140624  1
```

Now for what goes into inventory, each of these have a different expiration date

```
id  model       p_orddate   quantity
1   1000-0001   140615          90
1   1000-0001   140622          72
```

SUM of Orders =80
SUM of p_orders=162

So the output should be that I have 10 left with the expiration date from the 6/15 shipment AND 72 left with an expiration date of the 6/22 shipment. I hope this explains it better

Comment: You capture the timestamp and expiration date of receipt, and the timestamp of sale, but you are never matching the sale with a specific expiration date. At least, not from what I gather from your description. Please post the schema of the tables involved, you'll get better help.

Comment: The assumption I have to use is first in (P_orders), first out(Orders).

Comment: An 'expiration date' for items, is going to make the problem 'interesting'. In the regard that some process has to check and / or be notified when any item is due to expire. I would imagine that you have various 'lists' about the status of items, such as, 'about to expire', 'soon to expire' etc. You will need some process(es) to run continuously to maintain the lists. Looks like an interesting issue to solve. I have no idea about how to solve this for large numbers of items.

Comment: I am hoping to just summarize what is left (ie 30 @6/30/14 and 100 @7/15/14). I can group the P_orders (+) and I can group the orders (-)  is there a way to subtract from two different  rows from p_orders (ie if orders exceed the P_orders first row then subtract from both first and second row and give me the result of what is left?

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to include a couple of examples of the actual input rows and the expected output rows? And the processing that you did to get the output. That way we have a clear idea of how things are related.

Comment: Sorry about the format of my results....I have never posted DB information and dont know how to properly format